# WCF BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement in Ruby or Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wcf

I have an existing WCF service consumed by .NET clients and is now being planned to be consumed by Ruby / Java clients (our test framework is written in Ruby).

Is there any support/library in Ruby/Java that allows me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may need to be reworded. From what I understood, you have an existing WCF service consumed by .NET clients and is now being planned to be consumed by Ruby / Java clients.

You may know this, WCF allows you to configure [multiple endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx) for a service. So I suggest creating a second interoperable endpoint for your non .NET clients.

Your best bet is to go with `BasicHttpBinding` and `Text` message-encoding. Ofcourse, you may tweak this further, MSDN gives you the full list of system provided bindings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,you understood the question well.  I will edit it to reflect your wording.  We are considering the multiple-endpoints option but that would be purely for test purposes and developers are keen to avoid it.

Comment: What is the concern with multiple endpoints? It is a standard WCF pattern which eliminates redundant code and is configuration based. Looks like it suits your scenario quite well, curious to understand why your developers aren't keen on this approach.

Comment: I have not discussed it in detail yet but will do.